# How to convert a string to a runnable (unevaluated) function in Python

Tags: python, exec, eval

I have a code creating a string representing vars from my script:

```
"((((x) * (320)) + ((y) * (270))) + ((z) * (400))) + ((w) * (500))"
```

My goal is to **store** (not evaluate) it as a function:

```
f = ((((x) * (320)) + ((y) * (270))) + ((z) * (400))) + ((w) * (500))
```

where x, y, z and w are the actual variables in my Python script.

So that it can be dynamically changed with changing one or more of my variables.

Is there a library doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by *store*? Just assign to a name, or anything involving serialization?

Comment: @Sören I guess OP wants to "dynamically" make a function object, which would compute the given formula, which actually sounds interesting!

Comment: @j1-lee I prefer not to guess.

Comment: "Is there a library doing this?" Please note that such requests are explicitly off topic here, as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Doing it yourself is possible, but depending on what you find acceptable may be rather complex. I think the question is too broad as asked.

Comment: That said, if it is acceptable that the resulting function simply calls `exec` (or `eval`) on the string when it is called, passing in the "actual variables" as either the locals or globals for the call, then it is pretty straightforward to set that up using `lambda`. In that case, please clarify and I could show an example if you need it. [Better if](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) you try to work it out yourself first, though. It's not clear either why you need/want to do this, nor why you need help with it.

Comment: Note, `f = ((((x) * (320)) + ((y) * (270))) + ((z) * (400))) + ((w) * (500))` is not how you define a function in Python.

Comment: @j1-lee Here's a solution which does what was requested

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are wrong. It's quite possible to lazily evaluate this in python.

```py
>>> create_function=lambda s:lambda:eval(s)
>>> x=2
>>> y=3
>>> create_function('x+y')()
5
>>> z=create_function('x*y')
>>> z()
6
```

Comment: note, this goes against PEP8 style guidelines. `create_function=lambda s:lambda:eval(s)` should be `def create_function(s): return lambda : eval(s)` (indented, of course)

Comment: That's true, but I chose that style both because it was more similar to the OP's original one-liner, and because I personally believe it's more readable even under the PEP8 guidelines, which are just guidelines. Thanks for helping out future readers though.

Answer (score -1):

```py
import re
from typing import List, Any
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass
class Database:
    variables: List[str] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    expression: str = ''

def store_expression(database: Database, plain_expression: str) -> None:
    variable_regexes = r'[a-z]'
    # you can get the variables as str and store them
    database.variables = re.findall(variable_regexes, plain_expression)
    
    # Then you can replace the equation with {} and store it too
    database.expression = re.sub(r'[a-z]', '{}', plain_expression)

def eval_expression(database: Database) -> Any:
    return eval(
        database.expression.format(
            *database.variables
        )
    )

s = "((((x) * (320)) + ((y) * (270))) + ((z) * (400))) + ((w) * (500))"

in_memory_db = Database()
store_expression(in_memory_db, s)

x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
w = 4

result = eval_expression(in_memory_db)
print(result)
```

Comment: What is the point of `variables = [eval(variable) for variable in str_variables]`?? why not just `eval(s)`? And note, `fun` doesn't even return the value!

Comment: This doesn't work at all.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you're right, I thought I would need to get the value from the variables on the scope first, but a simple eval does the trick, thanks!
The question only asks for a way to store the expression and use variables from scope, that's why I didn't return the values. I hope that this current answer be more clear.

Comment: @Mous I see where you're confused, let me know if my edits help you to understand that the code is storing the expression and then using it to get the data from the scope.

Comment: This still doesn't work. Variable names can contain many, _many_ more characters than that set, which only works for one specific subset (alphabetical names) of a specific subset (one-character names).

Comment: If you wanted to go that route, I'd recommend reading https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers, but I don't think even that solves the issue because it would end up matching function or class names. Also, this solution seems really, really memory-inefficient if it's instantiating classes. _Even_ if you just wanted to store the variables from the scope of when your function was called, you could just do something like `create_function=lambda s:(l:=locals(),g=globals(),lambda:eval(s,g,l))[2]`, but there's absolutely no reason to do that, _ever_.

Comment: And to distinguish variables from, say, `not` or `class` or `__none__` or `__debug__`, etc is impractical.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, the typehint on eval_expression is wrong, it should be `Any`, because expressions don't only evaluate to objects of type `int`.

Comment: @Mous I'm aware of lexical analysis, but anyway you're right I really provided a specific solution for the problem. My route is way over-engineered, lazy evaluate the expression is the way to do it.